# Why is this asynchronous function being called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a user with email and password using firebase, but when I call the function that creates it, it is called twice and I get an error because I am trying to register the email that is already in use.

I noticed that the **console.log('CALLED')** is called once, I don't understand why **RegisterWithEmail** is called twice. My auth flow only creates the **userDocument** in the confirmation phase, for this reason **userSnap.length** equals zero in the second call and tries to create again.

**How can I call this function once?**

**FILE: emailconfirm.page.tsx**

```
registerEmail = async data => {
    const { setRegStatus, createDoc } = this.props;
    console.log('CALLED')
    await RegisterWithEmail(data).then(res => {
      console.log('Final response ', res)
      if(res === 'EMAIL_VERIFIED') {
        createDoc()
        setRegStatus({ status: 'created', data: res })
      }
      else if(res === 'SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG'){
        setRegStatus({ status: 'error', data: res })
      }

    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Error ', err)
      setRegStatus({ status: 'error', data: err })
    })
  }
```

**FILE: firebase.utils.tsx**

```
export const RegisterWithEmail = async user => {
  console.log("Called Once...");

  if(!user) return 'SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG';
  else {
    const snap = await firestore.collection('users').where('email', '==', user.email).get();
    const docs = snap.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());

    if (docs.length !== 0) return 'EMAIL_HAS_ALREADY_BEEN_TAKEN';

    try {
      console.log("Trying to register email...");
      return await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password).then(async usr => {
        await usr.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: user.name
        }) // SETTING NAME

        const sendVerifyEmail = usr.user.sendEmailVerification().then(() => setTimer(usr.user, 5))

        return await sendVerifyEmail.then(msg => {
          console.log('Finishing...', msg)
          if(msg.txt !== 'waiting') {
            if(msg.error) {
              throw msg.txt
            }
            else return msg.txt
          }
        }).catch(() => {
          throw 'EMAIL_NOT_SENT'
        })
      }).catch(() => {
        throw 'USER_NOT_CREATED'
      })
    } catch (err) {
      throw 'USER_ALREADY_REGISTERED'
    }
  }
}
```

**Developer console:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be mixing and matching `.then()`s in `async` functions for your own sanity's sake.

Something like

```
export const RegisterWithEmail = async (user) => {
  if (!user) return false;
  const snap = await firestore.collection("users").where("email", "==", user.email).get();
  const docs = snap.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
  if (docs.length !== 0) return false;
  console.log("Trying to register email...");
  try {
    const resp = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
    // then ...
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    // catch ...
  }
};
```

might work better for you.

Answer (score 0):

I need more code to be sure, but I think you should add `await`

```
registerEmail = async data => {
    console.log('CALLED')
    await RegisterWithEmail(data)
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and the @akx tip but it didn't work.